# Issue with ldap login

Tags: php, forms, ldap

The problem with this script when trying to log in is that, a user can log in with just a username in the username field and no password in the password field. They can also log in with the correct username and password. However, when using the correct username and wrong password, the log in fails. I've searched for a bit but couldn't find much. Here is what I have.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include('config/db.php');
    //echo phpinfo();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hdn_submit']) && $_REQUEST['hdn_submit']=="1"){ 

        $ldaprdn = $_POST['username'] . '@domain';
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $ldappass = $_POST['password'];
        //$ldapconn = ldap_connect(" old IP address",port)or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
        $ldapconn = ldap_connect("IP address",port)or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
        //echo $ldaprdn;
        if ($ldapconn)
        {
            //ldap_set_option($ldapconn,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3) or die("Could not set ldap protocol version");
            // binding to ldap server
            $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);
            // verify binding
            if ($ldapbind)
            {
                //login successfull 
                $_SESSION['checkin'] = date('d/m/Y h:i:s A');
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_REQUEST['username'];

                header('Location: index.php');

            }
            else
            {
                //echo 'hello';
                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Invalid Login. Please try again!")</script>;';
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = '0';

            }

        }

    }

 ?>

<?php  include_once('template/header.php'); ?>
<div class="row page-area">

  <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:300px; margin:100px auto;">
    <div class="panel-heading">User Login</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="">

          <?php if($msg!=''){ ?>
          <p class="bg-primary"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
          <?php } ?>

          <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus><br/>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="User Password" required><br/>
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
              Sign In
          </button>
          <input type="hidden" name="hdn_submit" value="1">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<?php  include_once('template/footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When they are "logging in" without a password it is highly likely that the backend directory server binding the session annoymously `anonymously`.

If you disabled anonymous binds on the directory server you should get failures.

Comment: I would add that you should validate that userID and a password VALUE are provided within you form and refuse to submit to the LDAP server without both having a "Real" value. (ie no empty strings or nulls)

Comment: Dave Bennet what if there were issues with disabling anonymous binds that were out of my hands? Is there an option of using a dedicated binding account?

Comment: jeemster , I can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks, I got it to work.

Comment: then just as @jeemster says, your app should prevent ldap connection attempts for empty passwords. If you are using the user's connection for anything it is likely that it may not contain the information you need if anonymously bound; it certainly would not permit updating.  But if you are using a service account for those things then you would basically have let teh person in the fron doo for free.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include('config/db.php');
    //echo phpinfo();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hdn_submit']) && $_REQUEST['hdn_submit']=="1"){ 

        $ldaprdn = $_POST['username'] . '@domain';
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $ldappass = $_POST['password'];
        //$ldapconn = ldap_connect("IP",port)or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
        $ldapconn = ldap_connect("IP",port)or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");
        //echo $ldaprdn;
        if ($ldapconn)
        {
            //ldap_set_option($ldapconn,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3) or die("Could not set ldap protocol version");
            // binding to ldap server
            if($ldaprdn!="" && $ldappass!=""){
                $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn,$ldaprdn,$ldappass);
                // verify binding
                if ($ldapbind)
                {
                    //login successfull 
                    $_SESSION['checkin'] = date('d/m/Y h:i:s A');
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_REQUEST['username'];

                    header('Location: index.php');

                }
                else
                {
                    //echo 'hello';
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Invalid Login. Please try again!")</script>;';
                    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = '0';

                }
            }else{
                    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Invalid Login. Please try again!")</script>;';
                    $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = '0';
            }

        }

    }

 ?>
```